# Table of contents similar to Jech's Set Theory

Tags: table-of-contents

I would like my content page to be the same format as Jech's *Set Theory*, which looks like this:
[image]

In particular, I want:

1. A "Part" which separates subcollections of chapters.
2. Sections appearing under each chapter as a paragraph, separated by some delimiter.

Please advise on how I can do this. Thank you.

Comment: You should take a look at the documentation of  `titletoc` ( a companion package of `titlesec`, §6 of the documentation of the latter package). In particular, its \titlecontents*{section}{…}` command groups the entries as a single paragraph.

Comment: You should problably give some more information about your document setup, class and packages for example